# Calling an Azure Function from SignalR negotiate

Tags: signalr

I have successfully been able to send my IoT Data to a SignalR Hub and within the Negotiate function I can call a script which will display it on a Brower. Everything is working perfectly. However today I am told that I need to be able to also call an Azure Function from the Negotiate but when I try, and put it above the return I get an error. Can anyone suggest how this can be done? Thanks! Mike

[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public static SignalRConnectionInfo GetSignalRInfo(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req,
[SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "MyHub")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
{
return connectionInfo;
}